# deploying django application without source code

Tags: python, django

I am working on a django project.
I am looking for a method for deploying my application and its update to production server.
I think the best way is to run a command which will push only pyc files, configurations files, templates and stuff on my server.
What is the best way to do this ? I do not want to deploy source py files. So i won't work with git or svn.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you're looking to do this? Whilst it's probably possible to do so (in the sense that "anything is possible"), it would generally be inadvisable.

Comment: Why do you think the best way is to push `.pyc` files?

Comment: May be you should use AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

You'd first have to compile all your .py files to bytecode

```
python -m py_compile  file.py
```

However, if you want this to hide sourcecode than you should know that there are ways to re-create python source from bytecode.

*But, as others have pointed out, why would you want to do that in the first place?*

Comment: i know how to compile a python file.
I just want to know how to deploy.

Comment: But you haven't explained *why*. There doesn't seem to be a good reason to want to do this.

Comment: because i do not want to expose source code if server is compromised (security)

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to push `.pyc` file, as per my knowledge `.pyc` file are generated on the fly when code executed and remain same based on the current system architecture until the file gets changed.

Comment: @Bob5421 it is easy to `uncompile` .pyc files https://github.com/Mysterie/uncompyle2 , so it wont help against that.

Comment: Okay so what should i do if i want to also deploy py files ?